# My students are losing their answers before submitting the form

Tags: google-forms

I do my assessments using Google Forms.  Things have been good so far until today.  This morning, two of my students who were taking their assessment, found that all of their responses had been blanked out.  This was a very long assessment.  several sections, with many questions in each section.  Of course, the only thing useful I got from them was "I think I clicked something somewhere".

Is there any way to make a form autosave periodically?  Or to recover information from a cache?  I'm telling my students this afternoon to be careful, and to copy and paste their answers into a separate google doc, just in case.

To be fair, I did also locate a third-party app called "Form Autosave" which adds a button in your browser, but that's not really the answer, since it is hardly "automatic" AND requires all my students to have it in their browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution because it is also third-party and poses the same issue of your students needing to install it on their browsers, but <strike>[Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno?hl=en)</strike> is a browser extension—link takes you to the Chrome Web Store; it is also available for Firefox—that automatically saves input in most text fields on the web for a set (adjustable) amount of time. It adds a little button to such text fields that, when clicked, opens a context menu that lists text it has saved for that particular field. If there are other fields on the page, it will automatically fill in the rest with the text that was there when it saved the selected text.

It should work with Google Forms.

Comment: Unfortunately *Lazarus* has been removed from the Chrome Web Store. It can be found though in [Softonic](https://lazarus-form-recovery.en.softonic.com).